# How to find the closest point in the DB using objectify-appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, persistence, objectify

I'm using objectify-appengine in my app. In the DB I store latitude & longitude of places.
at some point I'd like to find the closest place (from the DB) to a specific point. 
As far as i understood i can't perform regular SQL-like queries. 
So my question is how can it be done in the best way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at [GeoModel](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geospatial), which enables Geospatial Queries with Google App Engine.

**Update:**

Let's assume that you have in your Objectify annotated model class, a GeoPt property called `coordinates`.

You need to have in your project two libraries:

1. [GeoLocation.java](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates#Java)
2. [Java GeoModel](http://code.google.com/p/javageomodel/)

In the code that you want to perform a geo query, you have the following:

```
import com.beoui.geocell.GeocellManager;
import com.beoui.geocell.model.BoundingBox;
import you.package.path.GeoLocation;
// other imports

// in your method
GeoLocation specificPointLocation = GeoLocation.fromDegrees(specificPoint.latitude, specificPoint.longitude);
GeoLocation[] bc = specificPointLocation.boundingCoordinates(radius);

// Transform this to a bounding box
BoundingBox bb = new BoundingBox((float) bc[0].getLatitudeInDegrees(),
                 (float) bc[1].getLongitudeInDegrees(),
                 (float) bc[1].getLatitudeInDegrees(),
                 (float) bc[0].getLongitudeInDegrees());

// Calculate the geocells list to be used in the queries (optimize
// list of cells that complete the given bounding box)
List<String> cells = GeocellManager.bestBboxSearchCells(bb, null);

// calculate geocells of your model class instance
List <String> modelCells = GeocellManager.generateGeoCell(myInstance.getCoordinate);

// matching
for (String c : cells) {
    if (modelCells.contains(c)) {
        // success, do sth with it
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: my question is how can I use objectify for this, in GeoModel they use some kind of other persistence agent that enables them to perform GQL queries, which I can't do.

Comment: See my updated answer please. It provides guidelines on which libraries to use and a code snippet that can be used as a basis to make bounding box queries in a Objectify annotated model.

Comment: @RCB: you should use concepts from this article and apply them in your project. Also there is java version of this project and there is a workaround to make it work with objectify: http://brunofuster.wordpress.com/category/geomodel/