# App Engine search api GeoPoint search

Tags: java, google-app-engine, search, objectify, google-search-api

[The App Engine Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/) has a GeoPoint field. Is it possible to use it to do radius search? As in, given a GeoPoint, find all documents that fall within a certain radius.

As of right now it looks like [GeoSpecial Query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch) is by invitation only, so I am seeking a simple alternative that is easy for me to understand.

Also, if somehow this matters, I am using objectify and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671699/how-to-find-the-closest-point-in-the-db-using-objectify-appengine) is too complicated for me to understand how to implement it.

Comment: In Python, it's very simple -- per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_adv/lesson1 , all you need is to pass to `index.search` a query string such as `"distance(store_location, geopoint(-33.857, 151.215)) < 45000"` (adapted of course to use the specific geopoint and radius you want). In Java/objectify, I don't know any simpler way than the one you find too complicated. `Geospatial Queries` (in Alpha and invite-only, as you say) are for the datastore -- quite separate from the search API which works on separate documents and indices.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I think it should work for my case. It will be at least a day before I can test it as I am developing now. But thanks! I will tell you if it works.

Comment: I would ask Google for access to the geo query feature - probably by posting to the app engine google group.

Answer (score 0):

For radius search, use **proximitySearch** instead of **bestBboxSearchCells** (using in your reference url):

```
GeocellManager.proximitySearch(Point center, int maxResults, double maxDistance //...
```

Use can see in this link for details of methods:
https://github.com/theganyo/javageomodel/blob/ce43c507ff671eb6f0998f7c7d78fd0c3877dbe7/geocell/src/main/java/com/beoui/geocell/GeocellManager.java

And the example code, it is very straightforward:
https://github.com/theganyo/javageomodel/blob/master/geocell/src/test/java/com/beoui/utils/HowToUseGeocell.java

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Alex Martelli, the query string `"distance(store_location, geopoint(-33.857, 151.215)) < 45000"` would effectively yield the results you seek replacing `geopoint()` with the location you're looking near and replacing `45000` with the distance within which you'd like the results to be.

This query string is runtime agnostic and can therefore be used in the same way for both Python and Java runtimes.

If you've gone with a different approach, product or solution, feel free to post it here.